# Shape gradient in css

Tags: html, css

I tried for hours to make a shape gradient equal to the one at [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/). Actually my code don't show anything, can someone help me?

```css
a{
    background: linear-gradient(118deg,#328bf2,#1644ad);
    border-radius: 54% 46% 64% 36%/64% 42% 58% 36%;
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    top: -250px;
    left: 48%;
    width: 930px;
    height: 870px;
}
```

```html
<a></a>
```

Comment: Do you mean the [swirl background](https://laracasts.com/images/home/home-banner-blue-swirl.svg) at the Laracasts site?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Oh they are already using SVG ...

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I guess he meant the other shape when the window is reduced as he copied the same CSS code but it's working fine here

Comment: That shape would be an interesting challenge just with CSS. Probably not possible right now without doing some hacky thing.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro with a mix of radial gradient it can be done ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would consider some SVG for this in order to easily create the curved part of the shape then apply it as a part of a multiple background layer:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) left/calc(100% - 100vh) 100% no-repeat,
  url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" ><path d="M0 64 L64 64 C60 50 56 46 29.33 50.83 C15.33 53.16 10.5 40.33 17.16 27.66 C20 11.66 16.33 6.5 0 0 Z"  fill="white"/></svg>') right/auto 100% no-repeat, 
  linear-gradient(118deg,#328bf2,#1644ad); 
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Here  is a good online tool where you can easily adjust the shape:

[`http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0 64 L64 64 C60 50 56 46 29.33 50.83 C15.33 53.16 10.5 40.33 17.16 27.66 C20 11.66 16.33 6.5 0 0 Z`](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%2064%20L64%2064%20C60%2050%2056%2046%2029.33%2050.83%20C15.33%2053.16%2010.5%2040.33%2017.16%2027.66%20C20%2011.66%2016.33%206.5%200%200%20Z)

Simply append the current path to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

```
div
   {
     background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, 
     rgba((255, 0, 0, 0.8),.85),
     rgba((255, 0, 0, 0.6), .85)
     );
   }
```

Specially in here you can specify the angle of the gradient colors by adding - "to right bottom" keyword. also you can use this method in sass.